# Adding a (click) event handler directly to mat-step?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to add a click event handler directly to the `mat-step` element?

I tried adding one to `step 2` in this demo, but I don't see the click being logged:

The code that I tried:

HTML:

```
<mat-step label="Step 2" (click)="click()" optional>
 // Other stuff
</mat-step>
```

TS:

```
click() {
  console.log("CLICKED STEP 2")
}
```

[`Stackblitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-cnzwgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to reproduce the behaviour.

### Related Angular Material Issue

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18080

It only works when completed on step 1 is true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`(selectionChange)`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api#CdkStepper) event for parent tag which is `mat-horizontal-stepper`.

HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
    <mat-step label="Step 1" [completed]="step1Complete">
        <h4>Step 1</h4>
        <button (click)="toggleStep1Complete()" mat-flat-button color="primary">{{ step1Complete === true ? "Toggle:Complete" : "Toggle:Incomplete"}}
</button>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Step 2" optional>
        <p>Step 2</p>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Step 3">
        <p>Step 3</p>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

TS Code:

```
import { StepperSelectionEvent } from '@angular/cdk/stepper'; -- Better to use to get an intellisense about properties and available methods

selectionChange(event: StepperSelectionEvent) {
  console.log(event.selectedStep.label);
  let stepLabel = event.selectedStep.label;
  if (stepLabel == "Step 2") {
    console.log("CLICKED STEP 2");
  }
}
```

[`A working demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-ao844t)

> EDIT:

If you want every step should be clickable or available for user then you have to remove `linear` attribute of `mat-horizontal-stepper` or just set it to `false`.

[`Documentation`](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#linear-stepper)

Comment: Thanks - Great work - I filed an issue with Angular Material because it only works when completed is true on step one: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18080